# didAccelerate doesn't fire?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I can't get didAccelerate to trigger.  I have the delegate implemented in my header file.  I've set a breakpoint in the method:

```
- (void) accelerometer: (UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate: (UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    int i = 0;
}
```

I've tried it with two different apps but still nothing.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Jed: Why did you remove iPhone-SDK tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set accelerometer's delegate to self. BTW, did you try to check it on a real device?

Comment: Yes - I have tried it on a real device.  Setting the delegate to self worked.  thanks.